# Retrieving an element with XPath based on child elements

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XML document in the following format:

```
<CONFIGURATION>
<ADMIN REFERRER="BCTRD" REQUIRE_AGREEMENTS="true" ALLOW_UPGRADES="true" />
<LAYOUT HIDE_PRESELECTED_SERVICES="true" AGREEMENTS_PER_EXCHANGE="true"></LAYOUT>
<SERVICE ID="TRE" CODE="TRADER_EMINI" OPTIONAL_BROKER="true">
    <EXCHANGE GROUP="FOO"/>
</SERVICE>
<SERVICE ID="TR" CODE="TRADER">
    <DEFAULT/>
    <EXCHANGE GROUP="BAR"/>
</SERVICE>
</CONFIGURATION>
```

I am currently using this code block to retrieve the service code of the default service:

```
$serviceList = $this->xpaths->query('config',"//SERVICE");
foreach ($serviceList as $service) {
    if ($service->getElementsByTagName('DEFAULT')->length) {
        $serviceCode = $service->attributes->getNamedItem('CODE')->nodeValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

I suspect that it's possible to do this with one or two lines of XPath, but I haven't been able to figure out how. How would you format an XPath query to retrieve the service code I'm after?

Comment: i thhink //SERVICE[DEFAULT]/@CODE would do it, unless i'm misreading something.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I knew it would be something simple. I'm still trying to wrap my brain around the syntax.

I don't know how this site works really, but if you submit that answer, I can check it off as solved.

Comment: @michi Well for whatever reason, xpath still understood it.

Comment: @ColinM: yes, I know, I wasn't aware of the []... that's why I deleted my comment ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the 'CODE' attribute's value directly by using the following XPath statement

```
//SERVICE[DEFAULT]/@CODE
```

This basically is 'give me the attribute CODE from any SERVICE element that has DEFAULT child element.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another xpath:

```
//SERVICE/DEFAULT/../@CODE
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/CCzCn0